# VB.NET - If not Datagridview cell empty

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Gradebook -
I have 5 cells (Homeworks, Ex1, Ex2, Ex3, FinalExam) to fill in Datagridview, My app works with normal numbers but when the user type "0" in cells Then the grade wont display. (not sum) . Here a sample of my source code:

```
 Total = Val(HW + Ex1 + Ex2 + Ex3 + FinalEx) / 5
If Not (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) = String.Empty And
        (DataGridView1(i).Cells(3).Value) And (DataGridView1(i).Cells(4).Value) And
        (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value) And (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value) Then
            If Total >= 90 Then
                DataGridView1(i).Cells(7).Value = "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean then enter all 0's? I only see a grade for averages above 90. 
Is there more code for between 80 and 90?
If they score 100,100,100,100,0
That's 400/5 or 80. 
Do you have a grade for values under 80?

Comment: Yes if i want to enter all 0 the IF not work. (not sum) Also if i enter only one "0". (Not Sum). Yes i have a condition for value under 80. 70. 60. etc...

Comment: Can you show the rest of the if conditions? Maybe that is the issue?